# How to convert multiple files from mp4 to flv using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, ffmpeg, file-conversion

Assuming I had a bunch of videos sitting inside the directory `/home/user/videos/awaiting_conversion` how would I go about using cron to run a script similar to this one to batch convert each video into a different format?

`/bin/sh -c $'nice /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i \044'\'$'/home/user/videos/awaiting_conversion/video_file_1.mp4'\'$' -s \044'\'$'480x320'\'$' -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -ab \044'\'$'64k'\'$' -vpre fast -crf \044'\'$'30'\'$' -ar \044'\'$'22050'\'$' -f flv -y \044'\'$'/home/user/videos/converted/video_file_1.flv'\'$''`

The above script works fine for a single conversion, but:

1. It assumes that the name of the video is static/known (which will not be the case when batch converting).
2. It assumes that there is only one video to convert (which may or may not be the case), i.e. there's no "loop".
3. It leaves the original file in place instead of deleting it (which is what I would want to happen to prevent duplicate conversions).

The ultimate question would be how do I run that script for each video that exists inside `/home/user/videos/awaiting_conversion`, passing the file name as a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

checkFile(){
    [[ -s $1 && -f $1 ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

mp42flv(){
    for arg; do
        checkFile "$arg" || continue
        /usr/bin/ffmpeg \
            -i "$arg" \
            -s '480x320' \
            -vcodec libx264 \
            -acodec libmp3lame \
            -ab '64k' \
            -vpre fast \
            -crf '30' \
            -ar '22050' \
            -f flv \
            -y "${arg%.*}.flv" ||
                echo >&2 "Error treating $arg"
    done
}

if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    mp42flv "$@"
else
    while IFS= read -r a; do
        checkFile "$a" || continue
        mp42flv "$a"
    done
fi
```

### Usage

- with a glob `./script.sh /home/user/videos/converted/video_file*.mp4`
- with a filename `./script.sh /home/user/videos/converted/video_file_01.mp4`
- with [find](/questions/tagged/find) via a pipe `find /home/user/videos/converted -type f -name '*video*mp4' |./script.sh` (the script detect the use of `STDIN`)

Answer (score 1):

The `basename` command is your friend in this case. You can use the pattern...

```
VIDEOS = /home/user/videos
for srcfile in ${VIDEOS}/awaiting_conversion/*.mp4 ; do
    dstfile=${VIDEOS}/converted/`basename ${srcfile} .mp4`.flv
    convertcommand ${srcfile} ${dstfile}
done
```

basename strips the directory off the srcfile and strips the suffix too. Then you just prepend the new path and append the new suffix.

Be careful when automatically deleting the old srcfile. You can probably check a few things such as a) ffmpeg return code, b) file size of dstfile is a certain size or greater and perhaps c) have it play the new file for you automatically so you can quickly view it and then control-c out of the conversion or something if the quality is not right. If you just want to prevent duplicate conversions, best to move the file to another directory and then delete it once you confirmed its all working.